# Upgrade AWS lambda python 3.6 to 3.8 causing issues with pyjks

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pyjks

I have lambda function that works in Python3.6. I tried to update to 3.8 and I am getting below exception when running with pyjks library

```
def _load_keystores(data, passCode):
  logger.info('Load the keystore information')
  return jks.KeyStore.loads(data, passCode)
```

Exception

```
[ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/service_setup.py", line 40, in lambda_handler
    create_keystore(event, secrets_data, config_data, 
     keystore_prefix='secretKey')
  File "/var/task/keystore_compute.py", line 44, in _load_keystores
     return jks.KeyStore.loads(data, passCode)
  File "/var/task/jks/jks.py", line 484, in loads
     magic_number = data[:4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyStore.loads()` accepts a byte string as a `data` parameter, but your error indicates that `None` was passed instead. Check the `type(data)` and verify that it's `bytes` before passing it to `KeyStore.loads()`.

It's impossible to say from your example code where `data` is coming from, and how the version upgrade could affect it, but you are getting `None` instead of the byte string in it.